# C# : Populating form fields based on user selection using an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, textbox, populate

On my form, I have 2 fields set up. Location of item, and sub-area. I am trying to populate the sub-area field based on what location the user chooses. For instance, they choose "Location 4". The only 3 sub-areas for that location are, lets say, A, B, and C. Upon selection in the location box, the sub-area box will only display A, B, and C. I have all the locations and allowed sub areas in an xml file called appsettings.xml. How do I get the program to read in the xml file and allow the sub area field to only be populated with valid data? Below is an example of how I have my xml file set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <MerchandiseTrack>

   <Merchandise_Zones Application_Data="Test-Run">

      <KeyBoard_App>
        <AppString>c windows osk.exe</AppString> 
      </KeyBoard_App>

 <Storage_Location>

     <head id="Location">                // Name of box on app
       <body id="04">                    // Name of Location within the box
         <Sub-Area>A, B, C,</Sub-Area>   // Allowed sub-areas
       </body>
     </head>

     <head id="Location">                // Name of box on app  
      <body id="05">                     //Name of Location within the box
         <Sub-Area>P, L, R, B</Sub-Area> // Allowed sub-areas 
      </body>
     </head>

     <head id="Location">                // Name of box on app
      <body id="14">                     //Name of Location within the box
       <Sub-Area>A, X, C </Sub-Area>     //Name of Location within the box
      </body>
    </head>

  </Storage_Location>
 </Merchandise_Zones>
</MerchandiseTrack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a event on `SelectedIndexChanged`. Then you read the locationID and select the node from your file:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"path/to/file.xml");
        XmlNode subarea = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MerchandiseTrack/Merchandise_Zones/Storage_Location/head/body[@id=" + locationComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "]/Sub-Area");
        string[] areas = subarea.InnerText.Split(',');
        foreach (string area in areas)
        {
           subAreaComboBox.Items.Add(area);
        }
```

That includes that you do not (!) have a trailing comma on your list (as you have with your first location at the moment. If so, you have to extend the code to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the great start! Two questions: I'm not sure what the +locationID+ is supposed to be? My code wont compile with it. Secondly, where you have "//write sub-area target", I want to place the value directly into the sub-area box, so what do I need to do to implement that into the sub-area box?

Comment: The locationID is a variable that holds the same value as the id-attribute in the head-node. Let's clarify what you want then I edit my code: You have 2 textboxes and when you enter "04" in the first you want to have "A, B, C" in the second?

Comment: That's correct! They will choose a location (from a drop-down box) and based off the location, a list of choices will appear in the Sub-Area drop-down that pertain to the location. So if they select "04" in the location drop box, sub-areas "A, B, C" only will appear in the Sub-Area drop box

Comment: Yea sorry about that detail. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: No worries. But you should restructure your XML file. When you have multiple values, use multiple nodes, not a list in a single node.

Answer (score 0):

There are a fair few steps involved. I'd use `XDocument.Load` to load the document, then you'll need to bind it to the UI. If using WPF, some derivative of ItemsControl to enter the values, but the fact you mentioned TextBoxes is cause for caution. The same is even more true in ASP.NET, as all controls will need to be recreated, given the same ID and re-added to the page while loading ViewState in order for you to access them.

When you bind/recreate them, the key is to ensure all of the ID/Name attributes stay the same.

My personal experience has always been that dynamic controls in WPF are fiddle, but in ASP.NET are pretty difficult to get working properly.